# can we pass an sql query string as a param into report?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, param

Can we pass an sql query string as a param into *JasperReports* report? I want the query string be passed as a simple String type parameter into the report at run-time and the fields returned by this query be available for this report; is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Mannyee, yes of course, you can pass the formed SQL query.
It can be something like this:

```xml
<parameter name="queryString" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String">
...
<queryString><![CDATA[$P!{queryString}]]></queryString>
```

Comment: thank you Alex for the help; but if we set isForPrompting property to false; how can we pass the param(i mean the query) to the report at run-time ? Could you elaborate it for me a bit more for how can i decode the fields returned by this kind of query ?

Comment: @mannyee, if you passes parameter through the java code or from jasper server (web application) isForPropmting flag does not help you. The editor IReport uses this flag for debugging needs - when you set isForPrompting="true" the dialog will be appear.

Comment: @mannyee, in my sample I prepared query string in java code (for example it can be: select attr1 from table1 where attr2='code1'). This query is ready to be executed. You can pass something like this to IReport

Comment: i found this link. maybe will help you or someone else later.. http://oneinnateinfo.blogspot.com/2013/10/step-by-step-how-to-add-ireport-query.html