# Jasper reports with Java web

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating a java web application with jasper reports. In that project I have to create some reports. So far I managed to generate a report which have a specific query that is attached to the report itself with the following code.

```
Connection conn = util.db.getDbConnection();
String reportPath = "C:/test.jrxml";
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);

File outDir = new File("D:/jasperoutput");
outDir.mkdirs();

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "D:/jasperoutput/test.pdf");

System.out.println("Done!");
```

The above code is working perfectly. Now I want to pass a SQL Query as a string when creating the report. Can someone please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: you should pass java bean instead of SQL query to report. step 1 get data via SQL, step 2 pass data to bean and pass bean to report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871042/jasperreports-passing-parameters-to-query) & [optional where clause jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19401825/876298) & [can we pass an sql query string as a param into report?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7254149/876298)